# Explicitly distinguish similar queries in pg_stat_statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-stat-statements

pg_stat_statements is (thankfully) pretty smart at normalizing queries to aggregate stats regardless of the arguments you pass. However, I'm facing a situation where a particular query is called from many locations across our application and I would like to get separate statistics based on these various locations. Inspired by the [Marginalia library](https://github.com/basecamp/marginalia), I tried to append SQL comments to annotate the query. Unfortunately it doesn't work. See this example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'a@b.c' /* action: signup */
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'x@y.z' /* action: login */
```

What happens is that pg_stat_statements stores a normalized representation of the query with the first comment it sees:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1 /* action: signup */
```

Then, if I call the same query with different comments (or no comment at all), the stats will be aggregated into the same item. Comments are effectively ignored from the normalized query representation.

Is there any way to call equivalent SQL queries but have them tracked separately by pg_stat_statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an elegant and versatile solution. You can label your queries by prepending a dummy [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (`WITH` clause):

```sql
WITH signup AS (SELECT 1) SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'a@b.c'
WITH login AS (SELECT 1) SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'x@y.z'
```

These will be tracked separately with their name preserved in `pg_stat_statements`:

```sql
WITH signup AS (SELECT $1) SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $2
WITH login AS (SELECT $1) SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $2
```

Another advantage over [@nachospiu’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772001/365969) is that it works with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` as well as `SELECT` queries that don’t have a `WHERE` you can add dummy conditions to.

The downside is that it may not be easy to implement using ORMs.

Answer (score 6):

I think a possible solution to your problem. It is not the best solution, but maybe it is helpful for you.

You can add more restrictions to the WHERE clause of very similar queries located in different places, like "true = true" to "trick" pg_stat_statements and get separate statistics (At least in Postgresql 9.2 work).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'a@b.c'
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'x@y.z' AND true = true
```

pg_stat_statements output ("query" field):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? = ? 
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? = ? AND ? = ?
```

Comment: Confirmed to also work on PostgreSQL 12 and 13. That’s an awesome trick to keep in one’s tool belt. I feel guilty for not thinking about it. I switched my accepted answer to this since it’s definitely the most useful solution for someone looking into this.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with you, it is useful in this case but a bit untidy.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

If you need that, and the statement has a long duration, you can use `log_min_duration_statement` and aggregate the durations yourself.